# Why does my code say it can't find the . symbol?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
 HashMap <String, Integer> output = new HashMap <String, Integer> (); 
 for (int j = 0 ; j < np; j++) { 
   output.add(people, recived1);
   System.out.println(output);
```

when I compile the code it says:

```
error: cannot find symbol
output.add(people, recived1);
      ^
```

Comment: try put instead of add

Comment: It appears you are using a very old version of Java.  All versions from 7 to the latest tell you exactly which symbol was not found.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are working with Java here. The Java [Map interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) does not have an `add` method. Rather you use the `put(key, value)` method to add data to the map.

Generally, when the compiler says `cannot find symbol` it points to you using the API wrongly. It may be a misspelling or a misunderstanding. Use the API docs to help.